# `TypeError: env.getState` error when testing whole redux saga with selector using jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, redux-saga

I have a problem with testing whole saga. Tests are working correctly when there is no `yield selector` usage in the saga, but when I have any `selector` in saga then I get error `TypeError: env.getState is not a function`.

I created repo with an example. Code is only for showing what the problem is. Instructions how to run project is in the `README`

https://github.com/gunitguy/react-app-test

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. `runSaga` takes also `getState` function which return mocked state. [redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing/#testing-the-full-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing/#testing-the-full-saga)